# Office 365 SharePoint New List Experience Global Navigation Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am facing an Issue with SharePoint Online Global Navigation. My Global Navigation is showing correct in Classic Mode but in New Experience Mode the Values are cut in Navigation Drop Down. How can we customize the New List Experience CSS in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SPFx react script editor for this.
When you deploy this webpart to SharePoint online, you could use it just like script editor web part in classic mode.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Comment: Let me check it. I think it is possible to manipulate the Global Navigation using this web part.